# PDO FETCH_CLASS and Namespacing issue

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to use PDO::FETCH_CLASS on an object. I am using namespacing and just entering:

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Product');
```

or

```
$result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, '\Product');
```

results in PHP looking for `Product.php` in the root of the app.

I can successfully instantiate a new Product though using:

```
 $product = new Product();
```

So I know my name spacing is working.

Is this not possible? Or do I need to instantiate a Product first then populate it after from the query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suspect PDO does not look up aliased class names or resolve the current namespace. So you have to pass it explicitely:

```
= $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS,  __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Product');
```

Exactness nitpick: Note that while a single backslash does work, in single quotes it is intended to escape literal single quotes *and* itself.

Comment: ah, yes. Couldn't use __NAMESPACE__ , as its separate from the class,  but just used the full path 'app\controller\product'. which worked. Thanks.